# vim cannot check markdown spell

Tags: spell-checking

I do not mean to let vim check my spell automatically, so please do not tell me to add a `autocmd ...` line in my `vimrc`.

I created a `.md` file and put these contents in it:

```
8) good fftowndn
```

Then I run the command `:setlocal spell!` in the normal mode, but this does not check the wrong spell token of `fftowndn` in my contents. However, the spell checking works well if I comment the contents.

How could I make spell checking work with `.md` please ?

Edit: in other file types such as `txt` file, after I run `:setlocal spell!`, the error tokens of `fftowndn` will be highlighted but here I do not see this highlight in the markdown file.

Edit2:

I come to find that the spell checking works well for the title marked with `#`, `##`, ..., `######`, and from `#######` on there will be no checking. It is the same with my markdown contents. If I do not mark my contents, there will be no spell checkings.

Edit3:
after various trying, I got to find the problem is likely to be with this line in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = [
        \ 'vim',
        \  'html',
        \  'css',
        \  'erb=eruby',
        \  'go',
        \  'java',
        \  'javascript',
        \  'js=javascript',
        \  'json=javascript',
        \  'ruby',
        \  'sass',
        \  'sql',
        \  'xml',
        \  'cpp',
        \  'python',
        \  'bash=sh',
        \  'cmake'
        \]
```

I just need markdown to show highlight for me code in the block between '```' and '```' pairs, but I did not expect it will affect my spell check, how could I solve this?

Comment: Works for me. If you move the cursor to the "8" and then press `]s`, does it jump to "fftowndn"?

Comment: Note you need `setlocal spell spelllang=LANG` (i may have spelt `spelllang` incorrectly). Can you clarify the precise contents via a code block, and describe the expected versus observed behavior?

Comment: @Ralf No, at least I do not see highlight of the error tokens as does in the comments.

Comment: Extension to my comment above: If the cursor does not move on `]s`, it means that the spelling error is not detected. If the cursor would move, then it is a highlighting problem.

Comment: @Ralf Then maybe the spelling error is not detected. Is there any configuration items in the `.vimrc` that may switch off the spelling of markdown contents but not its comments?

Comment: what vim version? Are you using any custom markdown runtime files?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I built my vim from source, and the commit is `6259e5769dd5` and the version tag is `v8.1.0173`. I do not have other plugins exception the following: ctrlfs.vim, indentLine, nerdcommenter, tagbar, vim-airline, vim-bbye. Do this have impact on markdown spell checking ?

Comment: Do you have a custom markdown or html syntax file? If yes, move them away and retest.

Comment: @Ralf I do not think so, I moved away my ~/.vim, and the problem still exists. Besides, I moved away my vimrc file, the problem is then solved. Maybe problem is with vimrc, please see my edit show me how I can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possible workarounds:

1. Change the order of entries in `g:markdown_fenced_languages` so that `'java'` is mentioned before `'html'`.
2. Set the global variable `java_ignore_javadoc` to some value (like `let java_ignore_javadoc=1`)

Background:

The Java syntax file includes the HTML syntax file to do highlighting of HTML in javadoc comments. After this include, it sets `syntax spell default` to prevent spell checking on all texts. See [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/c8c8849267503b2d2d6d821047ee8619c7821728/runtime/syntax/java.vim#L158-L161).

By disabling spell checking for "all text" it disables the spell checking for markdown text.

When the global variable `java_ignore_javadoc` is set (workaround 2), the java syntax does not include the html syntax file and does not reset the `syntax spell` setting. Then spell checking works, but special highlighting for javadoc is disabled.

By reloading the html syntax after the java syntax (workaround 1), the setting `syntax spell default` (from java) is again overwritten with `syntax spell toplevel` from the html syntax. Hence spell checking works again.